# Custom Authentication Provider

Tags: php, symfony

I'll make a system using `Symfony` 2.6 (latest stable at time of writing).
We will authenticate only at intranet, but using a special URL for authentication.

Today method (in plain `PHP`) is:

- Receive request on any page;
- Verify if is logged in;
- If not, redirect to main page;
- In main page check if its logged in, if not redirect to a special URL on intranet ;
- Special URL returns the user login (Only if the user is in the intranet too) as parameter and redirect to login page;
- In the login page check if there is a login parameter;
- Login the user based on the login parameter;

How I'm supposed to do this in symfony 2?

I'm supposing I will need to implement a custom provider (which actually I already have for retrieving the user and the ROLES from database). The part I'm missing is checking the login and redirecting to special URL in intranet.

Comment: This is one of the more challenging tasks. Start here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html.  The "redirect to a special URL on intranet" sounds a bit like oauth.  Might take a look at HWIOAuthBundle.  The good news is that if you manage to get it working then you will know more about the security system than you ever dreamed possible.  I'd also suggest reading through the rest of the cookbook security entries.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have learned a lot about the security system and am actually building the authorization system.